# Build arm64 target build using pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, apple-silicon

Apple has recently launched Macs based on the Apple silicon processor which is Apples in house arm64 based processor.

I am using pyinstaller 3.4 and Python 2.7.18 to create application for Mac.
I tried on Catalina machine with latest Xcode 12. But pyinstaller creates build only for intel arch.

Is there a way to create build with Apple silicon arm64 target.

Comment: also looking for a way to cross build for arm32 and arm64 for Android